# decipher this Acer Aspire 4830TG ACPI code for Nvidia Optimus

Tags: linux, graphics, nvidia, acpi

I am trying to make sense of the following NVOP Method from the ACPI tables for an Acer Aspire 4830TG with an Nvidia Optimus hybrid graphics system. The NVOP method on top defines a bunch of instructions that can be used later on in the _DSM method. Which method should I call with the acpi_call module or the byo-switcheroo module to switch on/off the card on demand?

See the code below:

```
Method (NVOP, 4, Serialized)
{
    Name (_T_0, Zero)
    Store ("------- NV OPTIMUS DSM --------", Debug)
    If (LNotEqual (Arg1, 0x0100))
    {
        Return (0x80000001)
    }

    While (One)
    {
        Store (ToInteger (Arg2), _T_0)
        If (LEqual (_T_0, Zero))
        {
            Store (Buffer (0x04)
                {
                    0x61, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0C
                }, Local0)
            Return (Local0)
        }
        Else
        {
            If (LEqual (_T_0, 0x05))
            {
                Name (TMP5, Buffer (0x04)
                {
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
                })
                CreateField (TMP5, Zero, 0x04, DAVF)
                CreateField (TMP5, 0x04, One, LIDF)
                CreateField (TMP5, 0x08, 0x06, TOGN)
                CreateField (Arg3, 0x1F, One, NCSM)
                CreateField (Arg3, 0x19, 0x05, NCSN)
                CreateField (Arg3, 0x18, One, DIMK)
                CreateField (Arg3, 0x0C, 0x0C, ACTD)
                CreateField (Arg3, Zero, 0x0C, ATTD)
                If (ToInteger (NCSM))
                {
                    Store (ToInteger (NCSN), TOGN)
                }
                Else
                {
                    If (ToInteger (DIMK))
                    {
                        GETD (ToInteger (ATTD), ToInteger (ACTD))
                        Store (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.NTOI, TOGN)
                        Store (One, DAVF)
                    }
                }

                Return (TMP5)
            }
            Else
            {
                If (LEqual (_T_0, 0x06))
                {
                    Name (TMP6, Package (0x0F)
                    {
                        Ones, 
                        0x2C, 
                        Ones, 
                        0x2C, 
                        Ones, 
                        0x2C, 
                        Ones, 
                        Ones, 
                        0x2C, 
                        Ones, 
                        Ones, 
                        0x2C, 
                        Ones, 
                        Ones, 
                        0x2C
                    })
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI2, Index (TMP6, Zero))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI1, Index (TMP6, 0x02))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI4, Index (TMP6, 0x04))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI2, Index (TMP6, 0x06))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI1, Index (TMP6, 0x07))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI2, Index (TMP6, 0x09))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI4, Index (TMP6, 0x0A))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI1, Index (TMP6, 0x0C))
                    Store (\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.IDI4, Index (TMP6, 0x0D))
                    Return (TMP6)
                }
                Else
                {
                    If (LEqual (_T_0, 0x10))
                    {
                        Return (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GOBT (Arg3))
                    }
                    Else
                    {
                        If (LEqual (_T_0, 0x1A))
                        {
                            CreateField (Arg3, 0x18, 0x02, OPCE)
                            CreateField (Arg3, Zero, One, FLCH)
                            If (ToInteger (FLCH))
                            {
                                Store (ToInteger (OPCE), OMPR)
                            }

                            Name (RBUF, Buffer (0x04)
                            {
                                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
                            })
                            CreateField (RBUF, Zero, One, OPEN)
                            CreateField (RBUF, 0x03, 0x02, CGCS)
                            CreateField (RBUF, 0x06, One, SHPC)
                            CreateField (RBUF, 0x18, 0x03, DGPC)
                            CreateField (RBUF, 0x1B, 0x02, HDAC)
                            Store (One, OPEN)
                            Store (One, SHPC)
                            Store (0x02, HDAC)
                            Store (One, DGPC)
                            If (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GSTA ())
                            {
                                Store (0x03, CGCS)
                            }
                            Else
                            {
                                Store (Zero, CGCS)
                            }

                            Return (RBUF)
                        }
                        Else
                        {
                            If (LEqual (_T_0, 0x1B))
                            {
                                Store (Arg3, Local0)
                                CreateField (Local0, Zero, One, OPFL)
                                CreateField (Local0, One, One, OPVL)
                                If (ToInteger (OPVL))
                                {
                                    Store (Zero, OPTF)
                                    If (ToInteger (OPFL))
                                    {
                                        Store (One, OPTF)
                                    }
                                }

                                Store (OPTF, Local0)
                                Return (Local0)
                            }
                            Else
                            {
                                Return (0x80000002)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Break
    }
}

Method (GOBT, 1, NotSerialized)
{
    Name (OPVK, Buffer (0xE2)
    {
        /* 0000 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0008 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0010 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0018 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0020 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0028 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0030 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0038 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0040 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0048 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0050 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0058 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0060 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0068 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0070 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0078 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0080 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0088 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0090 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 0098 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00A0 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00A8 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00B0 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00B8 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00C0 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00C8 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00D0 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00D8 */    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        /* 00E0 */    0x00, 0x00
    })
    CreateWordField (Arg0, 0x02, USRG)
    If (LEqual (USRG, 0x564B))
    {
        Return (OPVK)
    }

    Return (Zero)
}

Method (_INI, 0, NotSerialized)
{
    Store (Zero, \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._ADR)
}

Method (GSTA, 0, Serialized)
{
    If (LEqual (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.PI17, One))
    {
        Return (One)
    }
    Else
    {
        Return (Zero)
    }
}

Method (_ON, 0, Serialized)
{
    \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.PWRE ()
    Store (Zero, LNKD)
    While (LLess (LNKS, 0x07))
    {
        Sleep (One)
    }

    Store (Zero, CMDR)
    Store (VGAB, VGAR)
    Store (0x06, CMDR)
}

Method (_OFF, 0, Serialized)
{
    Store (VGAR, VGAB)
    Store (One, LNKD)
    While (LNotEqual (LNKS, Zero))
    {
        Sleep (One)
    }

    \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.PWRD ()
}

Method (_PS0, 0, NotSerialized)
{
    If (DGOS)
    {
        GLSC ()
        \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._ON ()
        GLSR ()
        Store (Zero, DGOS)
        Store (Zero, MLTF)
        Store (Zero, \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.DSPM)
    }
}

Method (_PS3, 0, NotSerialized)
{
    If (LEqual (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.OMPR, 0x03))
    {
        GLSC ()
        \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF ()
        GLSR ()
        Store (One, DGOS)
        Store (0x02, \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.OMPR)
        Store (One, \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.DSPM)
    }
}

Method (_STA, 0, Serialized)
{
    Return (0x0F)
}

Method (_ROM, 2, NotSerialized)
{
    Store (Arg0, Local0)
    Store (Arg1, Local1)
    If (LGreater (Local1, 0x1000))
    {
        Store (0x1000, Local1)
    }

    If (LGreater (Local0, 0x00010000))
    {
        Return (Buffer (Local1)
        {
            0x00
        })
    }

    If (LGreater (Local0, RVBS))
    {
        Return (Buffer (Local1)
        {
            0x00
        })
    }

    Multiply (Local1, 0x08, Local3)
    Name (ROM1, Buffer (0x8000)
    {
        0x00
    })
    Name (ROM2, Buffer (Local1)
    {
        0x00
    })
    If (LLess (Local0, 0x8000))
    {
        Store (RBF1, ROM1)
    }
    Else
    {
        Subtract (Local0, 0x8000, Local0)
        Store (RBF2, ROM1)
    }

    Multiply (Local0, 0x08, Local2)
    CreateField (ROM1, Local2, Local3, TMPB)
    Store (TMPB, ROM2)
    Return (ROM2)
}

Method (MXMX, 1, Serialized)
{
    If (LEqual (Arg0, One))
    {
        P8XH (One, 0x99, P8XH (Zero, One, Return (One), Return (Zero)))
    }
}

Name (MXM3, Buffer (0x45)
{
    /* 0000 */    0x4D, 0x58, 0x4D, 0x5F, 0x03, 0x00, 0x3D, 0x00, 
    /* 0008 */    0x30, 0x10, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xF9, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 
    /* 0010 */    0x00, 0x01, 0x8A, 0xFF, 0xF9, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 
    /* 0018 */    0x60, 0x79, 0xD0, 0xFE, 0xF9, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 
    /* 0020 */    0x20, 0x2B, 0xE2, 0xFE, 0xF9, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 
    /* 0028 */    0x60, 0x6C, 0xEA, 0xFE, 0xF9, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 
    /* 0030 */    0x01, 0x90, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x90, 0x01, 
    /* 0038 */    0x13, 0x00, 0x90, 0x01, 0xE5, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 
    /* 0040 */    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x96
})
Method (_DSM, 4, Serialized)
{
    Name (_T_0, Zero)
    If (LEqual (Arg0, Buffer (0x10)
            {
                /* 0000 */    0xF8, 0xD8, 0x86, 0xA4, 0xDA, 0x0B, 0x1B, 0x47, 
                /* 0008 */    0xA7, 0x2B, 0x60, 0x42, 0xA6, 0xB5, 0xBE, 0xE0
            }))
    {
        Return (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.NVOP (Arg0, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3))
    }

    If (LEqual (Arg0, Buffer (0x10)
            {
                /* 0000 */    0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x40, 0x7D, 0x91, 0xF2, 0x4C, 
                /* 0008 */    0xB8, 0x9C, 0x79, 0xB6, 0x2F, 0xD5, 0x56, 0x65
            }))
    {
        While (One)
        {
            Store (ToInteger (Arg2), _T_0)
            If (LEqual (_T_0, Zero))
            {
                Return (Buffer (0x04)
                {
                    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01
                })
            }
            Else
            {
                If (LEqual (_T_0, 0x18))
                {
                    Return (Buffer (0x04)
                    {
                        0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00
                    })
                }
                Else
                {
                    If (LEqual (_T_0, 0x10))
                    {
                        If (LEqual (Arg1, 0x0300))
                        {
                            Return (MXM3)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Break
        }

        Return (0x80000002)
    }

    Return (0x80000001)
}
```

The original ACPI tables are available here:
http://bugs.launchpad.net/lpbugreporter/+bug/752542/+attachment/2235754/+files/Aspire%204830TG.tar.gz

http://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call
http://github.com/awilliam/asus-switcheroo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analyzing the code you posted as well ass `acpi_call` leads me to the the conclusion that most probable candidates should be:

```
echo '\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF' > /proc/acpi/call
```

to turn the card off and

```
echo '\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._ON' > /proc/acpi/call
```

to turn it back on again.

You *should* be safe to test those, as the `README` for `acpi_call` states:

> It SHOULD be ok to test all of the methods

And `\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF` is one of the methods tested in their `test_off.sh` script. At the same time, it is the only `..._OFF` method appearing in your ACPI code.

**If those do not work** as you'd expect, you might try instead `\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._PS3` for suspending and `\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._PS0` for resuming. In your code, these methods seem to call the `..._OFF` and `.._ON` with some additional tests etc. Their names also suggest relation to switching between power on/suspend states.

Comment: @avilella Well, have you tried it? Or is it not the type of answer you were looking for?

Comment: so would it be ok to call _PS3 and _PS0 even if one only wants to switch the card on/off?

Comment: Well, I can't guarantee you that - but from what I understand how ACPI works, if it doesn't, then in the worst case you'd have to shutdown and restart your computer. So I'd just try. Only the manufacturers can **really** know, what exactly each function does. What you must hold on to is their naming schemes - and intuition :)

Comment: But for sure, I'd first try the `\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF`, since it is one of the default method names known to `acpi_call`.

Answer (score 1):

Directly calling `_ON` and `_OFF` is not recommended. I have analysed many ACPI tables for the "correct" ACPI methods that allow you to toggle the power state and have concluded that there are two generic methods that do disable the Nvidia card.

Your laptop seems to support both methods according to SSDT4 file on Launchpad. Performing ACPI method calls using `acpi_call` is not the recommended way to toggle power as it breaks with suspend. You should use [`bbswitch`](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch) instead, a method that *does* properly handle toggling the power on suspend / resume. (disclosure: I am the author of it)

For more technical details, see http://wiki.bumblebee-project.org/ACPI-for-Developers. I have done a comparison between acpi_call, bbswitch and vgaswitcheroo on http://wiki.bumblebee-project.org/Comparison-of-PM-methods.